# What are common routes from Shadowdale to Waterdeep?

Tags: lore, forgotten-realms, travel

The party I DM has completed their adventures in the Dalelands (Shadowdale and Daggerdale) and wants to travel to Waterdeep. The party is fairly low level, so their travel will be non-magical and not too expensive. The time period is the 1350s DR, the geography is similar to 5e but not to 4e. What are common routes from Shadowdale to Waterdeep? Bonus points for the time various routes take.

I've accepted the excellent answer from @RevenantBacon for mundane water and land based transportation to Waterdeep. In Shadowdale in 1355 DR (year of the Harp) the two spell casters high enough level to cast teleport are Elminster and Sylune (she dies in 1356 DR, year of the Worm). Neither of them casts spells for money so they would have to decide that the parties need is great enough to help them. The parties motive for travel is to escape the wrath of the lords of Zhentil Keep and the Zhentarim. My call is that El and Sylune view the journey as a learning experience for the party as they cross Faerun.

Comment: Alternatively, [the Marco Volo adventure trilogy for 2e](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Marco_Volo) (spoiler alert!) discusses a trip overland in the opposite direction, from Waterdeep to Shadowdale. The choice of route is not really up for discussion in the adventures. Out-of-universe, that is because the encounters were set in specific places, but in-universe, you could argue that the Volo route is canonical, so the reverse route would be canonical as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### This is going to be a significantly long journey.

I'm not sure if your party realizes just *how far* it is from The Dalelands to Waterdeep. For reference, it's roughly 1,200 miles as the crow flies. Unfortunately, however, there is no direct travel route that takes you on a straight line from Shadowdale to Waterdeep. There's the Desertsmouth Mountains, the Marsh of Chelimber, The High Moor, the Serpent Hills, and even the Anauroch Desert, all of which would have to be passed through or circumvented, so we'll probably want to take a roundabout route.

<sub>*Disclaimer: all distances are approximate. I have a huge poster map of the sword coast on my wall that I took down and measured these distances with a ruler, but these are still only approximate distances. The edition that the map represents should be mostly irrelevant, as the overall topography of the land hasn't really changed*</sub>

---

#### The Means of Travel

The first things we want to figure out is what the fastest means of travel is, so we know which route to take, or when to switch means of travel should one option become unusable. For travel method, we have several options.

- **Land Travel:** A normal travel pace is 24 miles per day, which assumes 8 hours of traveling per day at a pace of 3 miles per hour on a road. Travelling through the wilderness would likely decrease this pace by some margin, so we'll prefer sticking to roads. We can increase our pace to 30 miles a day, but then we take a -5 penalty to Passive Perception, making encounters more likely, or we can slow our pace to 18 miles per day, but allowing us to use stealth, and make encounters less likely.
- **Water Travel:** There are a few types of boats that we can travel on, each with different speeds. If the characters have enough funds, they could buy passage on a boat, though this would likely be quite expensive because of the distances we need to travel. Alternatively, they could work for their passage as sailors and mercenaries defending the boat in case of pirate attacks. The main advantage of boats is, they keep moving even when part of the crew is resting, effectively giving them round-the-clock movement. Obviously, the faster boats would be preferable, but availability of boats in port will be up to you as the DM. For boats we have

  - **Galley:** 4 MPH or 96 miles per day
  - **Longship:** 3 MPH or 72 miles per day
  - **Warship:** 2.5 MPH or 60 miles per day
  - **Sailing Ship:** 2 MPH or 48 miles per day
  - **Rowboat:** 1.5 MPH or 36 miles per day - a bit faster than fast-pace travel
  - **Keelboat:** 1 MPH, or 24 miles per day - about the same as normal pace travel

These are going to be the two main types of transportation available to the players, anything else will likely be too expensive. Since boats are obviously the much faster option, we'll want to stick to them whenever possible. Unfortunately, no single waterway connects Waterdeep to the Dalelands, so some land travel is unavoidable. With this information in mind lets take a look at possible routes.

---

#### The Route

Luckily for us, we can at least start our journey on the water, as Shadowdale lies on the River Ashara, a rather large river that can accommodate even the largest of ships, allowing us to get a decent start on our journey, jumping onto a ship right off the bat. We'll take it down to Scardale, on the coast of The Dragon Reach, which is the Northernmost portion of the Sea of Fallen Stars, in a journey of about 500 miles. One there, we'll look for a ship headed for the city of Proskur on the Westernmost edge of The Dragonmere, the farthest west portion of the Sea of Fallen Stars, another 900ish miles.

We disembark at Proskur, and from here start the first (and hopefully only) land travel portion of the journey. We take the Road 150 miles west to the City of Irieabor, which lies on the shores of The River Chionthar. The river over 700 miles of land, all the way to The Sea of Swords, and passes right past Baldur's Gate, which, assuming that that's as far as our current ship is travelling will be where we book out final voyage, a mere 550 miles to the city of Waterdeep.

So, we're looking at a grand total of about 2,650 miles of sea travel, along with about 150 miles of land travel. Assuming a common sailing ship for each stretch of water travel, and a normal pace for the land travel, we're looking at a travel time of about 55 days of sea travel, 6 more days of land travel, and possibly a few additional days here and there waiting for a ship to be available that's heading in the right direction. **All told, we're looking at somewhere along the lines of just over two months of travel time.**

[image: Sword Coast Map]

---

#### Other Means of Travelling

A few more travelling options that I left out from the main I will list here, for completeness.

- **Teleportation magic:** Either *Teleport* or *Teleportation Circle* will get you to Watedeep in quite literally an instant. Considering [some](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Elminster_Aumar) [of](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Halaster_Blackcloak) [its](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Khelben_Arunsun) [denizens](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Xanathar), and the fact that many major temples and guilds will have permanent circles, you're quite literally guaranteed that there will be a teleportation circle to target, though those circles may not be in the safest locations, and may constitute the parties first adventure in the area! The main preventative, of course, is learning the sigil sequence to one of those circles, and then working up enough money to pay someone to teleport them there, or enough levels to do it themselves. The cost market standard cost for getting someone to cast a level 5 spell for you (based on the cost for Raise Dead) is roughly 750 GP plus the cost of any components that are consumed by the casting (in this case, 50GP worth of special chalks), although some spellcasters, may instead offer to cast it for them in exchange for the party performing a task of the casters choice (read: do a quest). The head of one of Myth Dranors temples might offer the use of his temples circle to travel to their sister-temple in Waterdeep, in exchangfe for investigating some recent goings-on in the surrounding forest. Since Myth Dranor is just a few days travel from Shadowdale, this could cut down on the total travel time by more than 90%! Considering that this is a party of adventurers, working up the 800GP required to get someone to cast *Teleportation Circle* to get us to Waterdeep might actually take *less* time than travelling there by boat.
- **Airships:** The other, final option, is air travel. I leave this one for last since it's the least likely to become available to the players as an option. A standard airship, like the one from Storm Kings Thunder, travels at about 8 miles per hour, and like the water ships, it can travel constantly, instead of needing to stop after only traveling for a small portion of the day. This gives it a travel rate of a whopping 192 miles per day. If it happens to catch a tail wind, it gets boosted to 12 miles per hour, or a truly rapid 288 miles per day, although with a headwind, they'd be slowed to the same pace as a galley, 4 miles per hour. This means, however, that they could be to Waterdeep in just 5 days with a strong tailwind, or worst case scenario, just under 2 weeks with a strong headwind the entire journey. Like I said, though, this is the least likely for them to have access to, both because airships are exceedingly rare, and because chartering passage on such a ship would be prohibitively expensive for low level adventurers.

Comment: You could also estimate the cost of the two month of ship/land travel per person, if you have any numbers for that.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir I actually don't know where to look for the cost of passage on a ship.

Comment: I tried and failed to use this [extremely hi-red[(https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/forgottenrealms/images/3/36/Sword-Coast-Map_HighRes-Compressed.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160307175412) image to draw the route for you, but I couldn't even find shadow dale. Do you think you'd be able to?

Comment: @RevenantBacon If we're talking 5th Edition, there's a price list in the Equipment Chapter for Services in the PHB. Ship's Passage is 1sp per mile, or you can book a carriage (and thus travel at 'horse' pace overland) for 3cp per mile. So if you take the route you proscribed, you're looking at 265gp per character in passage fees, plus an extra possible 4.5gp in carriage fees if they don't want to hoof it overland. y'know...plus food. (Note: costs are the same in 3.5E as well)

Comment: The party has the money for water travel, but the more exotic items are definitely out of reach. The best item anyone has in the party is a +1 sword and around 500 GP each.

Comment: "The edition that the map represents should be mostly irrelevant, as the overall topography of the land hasn't really changed" on the contrary, from 2e to 3e the map was tilted and stretched to fit the more rectangular poster and a lot of wilderness disappeared.

Comment: @Zachiel I have maps from multiple editions, including 1st, 2nd, and 5th edition (somehow missed the 3/3.5th and 4th ed maps). The difference between the maps is largely relegated to The Worldwound and the Shining Sea, neither of which we come anywhere near passing through, as those are both much farther south that The Dalelands. Also, the slight tilting and stretching of the map to fit a certain page size ratio doesn't actually change the map itself, just the scale of it.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin. The teleportation circle thing seems to be cheaper (800 GP for the entire party) than ship travel (265 GP times party size, plus food etc for a few months).

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir To be fair, I'm only guessing at the cost for *Teleportation Circle*, but I was actually surprised by how much it would cost to travel by boat such a long distance, as I somehow missed the travel pricing. They'll definitely want to work for their supper for at least part of the journey.

Comment: The party are members of the Harpers so they are going to work for a traveling circus for part/most of their trip. I've wanted to work in tamed Owlbears and traveling with circus seems like a perfect opportunity for some hooted hi-jinks.